# Transaction metrics mismatching in google core reporting API

Tags: java, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am using core reporting API-3.0 for getting google analytics data. The metrics ga:transactions is not matched to Query explorer tool in Google Developers. I am using the following metrics and dimensions

```
    analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + profileId, // Table Id. ga: + profile id.
            "2015-10-26", // Start date.
            "2015-11-01", // End date.
            "ga:sessions, ga:users, ga:transactionRevenue,ga:transactions") // Metrics.
            .setDimensions("ga:country")
            .setSort("-ga:users")
            .execute();
```

My profile is currently web only. I dont know why all those metrics are little differed to original data.Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried setting the sample rate?

Comment: No..How to set the sample rate

Comment: setSamplingLevel("HIGHER_PRECISION")    Guessing here.

Comment: after adding setSamplingLevel() still it was same result..pls help me.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the accuracy of the query explorer tool I would check the Google Analytics website.

Comment: google analytics website also giving the same results.

Comment: Does the result [contain sampled data](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#containsSampledData)? If so you could try querying for a shorter time frame, until `containsSampledData == False`. The query explorer tool uses the Core Reporting API its all open source and [available on github](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools)